# Isometric immersion of Bierbebach

Tags: differential-geometry, hilbert-spaces, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I'm analyzing the following isometric immersion of $\mathbb H^2$ in $\mathbb R^\infty$ given by $f(x,y)=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{2m-1},x_{2m},\dots)$ with
\begin{align}\label{5.1}
    x_{2m-1}=\operatorname{Re}\frac{(x+iy)^m}{\sqrt{m}},\quad x_{2m}=\operatorname{Im}\frac{(x+iy)^m}{\sqrt{m}},\quad m=1,2,\dots
\end{align}
I tried to check that it really is an isometric immersion, but I cannot calculate $f^*g_{\mathbb R^\infty}=g$ or give it shape, I have tried to do it by means of its polar representation but I have gotten confused without reaching anything concrete. Any ideas how to attack this problem?

[Here](https://www.e-periodica.ch/cntmng?type=pdf&pid=com-001:1932:4::24) I leave the original document.

My attempt was: $\color{red}{[\rm{Updated}]}$

> Instead of taking real variable I take complex variable, that is let $z_m=\dfrac{\color{red}{2}z^m}{\sqrt{m}}$, donde $z_m=x_{2m-1}+ix_{2m}$. Then $dz_m=\color{red}{2}\sqrt{m}z^{m-1}dz$, thus
> \begin{align*}
> \varphi^*g_\infty&=\sum_{m=1}^\infty dx_{m}^2\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty (dx_{2m-1}^2+dx_{2m}^2)\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^\infty |dz_m|^2\\
> &=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\color{red}{4}m|z|^{2(m-1)}|dz|^2\\[2mm]
> &=\color{red}{4}|dz|^2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}m|z|^{2(m-1)}\\[2mm]
> &=\color{red}{4}\frac{|dz|^2}{(1-|z|^2)^2}\\[2mm]
> &=\color{red}{4}\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{(1-(x^2+y^2))^2}\\
> &=g_D
> \end{align*}

Comment: A few comments. It’s better to work entirely in complex coordinates, I think. $\Bbb H^n$ must be a typo, since $n$ appears nowhere. The factors of $\sqrt m$ seem wrong. And I assume this is the disk model of $\Bbb H$?

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right it was a typo. In the original article it is not mentioned which model is used for this dive, I tried to get it through the Pullback but I got lost as I mentioned.

Comment: I take it back. The $\sqrt m$ is correct. Hint: What is $\sum kx^k$ for $|x|<1$? Start by writing the metric as $\sum |dz_m|^2$ and pull back $dz_m$.

Comment: Oops. Slightly wrong hint. $\sum kx^{k-1}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am leaving the original document in the same question, so that it can be better understood. I tried to use what you mention by putting together the coordinates I have, to use complex coordinates but I got lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very, very close. At the end, write
$$\Big(\sum_{m=1}^\infty m|z|^{2(m-1)}\Big)|dz|^2  = \frac 1{(1-|z|^2)^2} |dz|^2,$$
using $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1} = \dfrac d{dx}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \dfrac d{dx}\Big(\dfrac1{1-x}-1\Big)=\dfrac 1{(1-x)^2}$ for $|x|<1$.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thank you.